# Clean Architecture and DDD Java

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I have organised my projet API in many modules for example : Authentification and Order in clean architecture for each module

But both module interact with the same Table User in the Database

Should I have to copy the UserEntityJpa in each module or add an new module called Common and put this jpa entity inside this commonModule ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "bounded context" by module? Do they share the exact meaning of the user? If yes, you can share the model in another module named SharedKernel. Otherwise, define a user entity in both modules.

Answer (score 0):

Both are rights. As you wish.

But if the UserEntityJpa is only a DTO or POCO from the Repository or DataLayer class, it will belong to an infrastructure module like Infrastructure.Repository or Infratructure.DataLayer.

In case you also divide this module (I mean Infrastructure.Repository) into two modules respecting the same distribution in the domain layer, you will face the problem of common tables that you mentioned, and you may need this type of module. like Infratructure.Repository.Common

I think the most important ones are the entities in your Domain/Core module.
If you are defining the Authentication module and the Order module, it is important to define two domain entities: one for each module.

- The authentication module can see the User as an Account (authentication identifier and possibly a password).
- Order module see User as Customer which contains more details, email, address...

Each module, when trying to create the corresponding entity, can use the same IUserRepository to fill in a part or the home entity needed in the Domain/Core layer.

UserEntityJpa as you see is just a representation of your data in the database, which participates in the construction of the Core entity, this should not impact the design of the Core module.

I want to note that this is a way of working. Some developers do not prefer this method and prefer to have the repository return a domain entity and avoid data mapping. They are different ways of thinking and that does not mean that one is right and the other is wrong. Each has its advantages and disadvantages. It depends on the context.

**NOTE**: I see Authentication in the Application layer and Order in the Domain/Core layer. Take a look please at the vertical and horizontal distribution of app design.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends on the meaning you are giving to this `UserEntityJpa` class you mention. If it is just a vessel of data from the database to your application services, for instance, or if is supposed to be a snapshot of what is in the database and will be converted to something in the domain, then you can maintain it in a common section of your architecture and use it for both `Authentication` and `Order`.

If instead the presence of `Entity` in the class name is suggesting that this class is part of the domain and representing an entity of it, then I will elaborate further in the following, just suggesting in this case that you change the name of the class to something extracted from the ubiquitous language (e.g., `User` instead of `UserEntityJpa`).

I will do the hypothesis here that by module you do not mean different and perfectly separated *bounded contexts*, that is, strategical division of your domain that you create in the *solution space*, as a design choice. I say that because you decided to make the two “modules”, as you call them, share the same source of data, thus admitting that they are sharing a core (a shared kernel indeed, as someone mentioned in the comments). If this is the case, you may decide:

- either to keep things as they are, creating a shared kernel between the two contexts;
- or to understand if you are not trying to squeeze a read model and a write model in the same architecture, as if it were a CQRS. Is your `Authentication` only thought for writing data and `Order` for reading data as a reflection? Or viceversa? Is one context the read model of the other? If that is so, treat them as separate model where one writes data in the shared db and the other reads data from the shared source as if they were reports.

Consider in any case that a clear separation of contexts may be actually not a bad design choice, as it may be that the concept of `User` in one bounded context is different from the one in the other bounded context. Consider for instance the case in which your system models a `Student` in a university; the `Student` is a person doing exams and participating to courses for the context “teaching”, while is a person paying taxes for the context “administration”. In your case, it may be that `User` is an entity holding credentials and roles for the context “authentication” and an entity with biographical data and orders for the context “order”.
If you go down this road of separating the contexts, then you can decide a strategy to make your bounded contexts “talk” together so that they do not pollute each other.
For instance, you may decide that the two bounded contexts are maintained aligned via the exchange of *domain events*: the first bounded context raises an event every time something relevant happens; the second bounded context is recipient for those events and reacts to them accordingly. This will make the two bounded contexts *eventually consistent*, that is, the actions on the first bounded context at a certain point in the future will reflect on the second bounded context, and you accept that for a brief moment in time the two contexts may be misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

In DDD, you often model entities within each bounded context.

If User has different meanings or roles in the context of Authentication and Order, it might make sense to have different representations in each module, tailored to the needs of that module.
This approach may lead to some duplication but keeps the models in each module focused on their specific context.